# Are there any ways to decrease the impressively long save times for Sims 3 worlds?

Tags: the-sims-3

I've been watching my wife play Sims 3, and I've noticed the save times are impressively long. (Load times are fine.)

The save times start off fine on a new world but after a few hours probably take longer to save than her computer would take to install an operating system a few times.

She has a fair number of expansions, but the save times are literally upwards of 10-20 minutes once a world gets somewhat developed.

This is on a brand new i5 processor with 8GB of memory, a Samsung SSD, a fairly good 1GB graphics card with nothing else but Windows 8, Chrome, Steam, and TF2 installed.

Is there any way to fix the unreasonably long save times with this game?

Comment: Does this only occur in Sims 3? What is the general size of the file? What happens if you try to save a text file using notepad or something around the same size?

Comment: I'm not sure about notepad specifically, but other file operations work fine. It copies things, extracts, etc. as fast as an SSD would be expected to.

Comment: I don't plays Sims, but the Q intrigued me. I did a quick google search and I see people reporting saves as large as *1.5 GB* (!) And a possible hint that Sims' "Memories" (specifically the photos) may be the root of the issue.

Comment: Well, she doesn't have that one installed, but she has quite a few add-ons. I just have never heard of a game taking so long to save.

Comment: Maybe ensure the save location is excluded from virus scanning too.

Comment: That's a good note, no anti-virus in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not going to fix the entire issue since I've never encountered save times as long as you are describing, but I've noticed that the save time also depends on what is currently displayed on your screen.

What I mean is that performing a maximum zoom in the middle of a room or in the garden seemed to reduce the save time.
In my case it was maybe going down from 1 minute to 30 seconds, so I'm not sure about the impact it would have on your side, but it's still worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

The general view I got from a quick google search would be that Sims3 is quite RAM intensive whilst saving, but that doesn't seem to be an issue for you with 8GB of RAM available.

However, I have seen a couple of forum topics come up in search results that, although are aimed more at loading times, might help with save times as well.

[Link 1](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/forum/index.php?topic=7200.0)
[Link 2](http://www.carls-sims-3-guide.com/forum/index.php/topic,2062.0.html)

Comment: Links to forums where they recommend useless programs to boost a computers speed should be taken with a big grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the reason for long save time can either you are using game mods that are heavy or the game is fragmented or  you have a low config system
To solve this problem you n ed to download razer game booster(Razor game booster][1](http://www.razerzone.com/gamebooster))
when installed go to utilities and defrag you games and download advanced system care  that will tune up your system

http://download.iobit.com/asc-setup.exe